# Return async result - efficient handling of synchronous case

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11, future

You can have an async API like this

```
std::future<int> GetAsync()
```

There are cases when for example you already have the result cached and would like to return the future initialized with the result. Is there a way with current standard (or proposal) to achieve that without recurring to creating an additional std::promise or making an additional async (with launch policy deferred) ?

**EDIT**

Consider also the case when result is computed based on some state local to GetAsync() function and the need to capture that probably by value in case one chooses to use std::async with launch policy deferred

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: I don't see this as a premature optimization at all. You have an API that is mostly async but many cases where it would handle responses on the same thread, so you have to ask yourself how to return in the sync case.

Comment: Exactly as you suggest with a `promise` or deferred `async`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm obviously misunderstanding something, why can't you just do this:

```
std::future<int> GetAsync()
{
  if (/*already got result*/)
  {
    std::promise<int> p;
    p.set_value(/*result*/);
    return p.get_future();
  }  
  return std::async(/*whatever is needed*/);
}
```

What is wrong with creating a promise?  If you want to get a result from a future (an asynchronous return object) you need an asynchronous provider, a `promise` is such a type.

Comment: That was the way I implemented it, but this seems to be quite a common use case, hence the proposal from n3428 - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3428.pdf

Comment: I don't understand why N3428 says it's non-trivial, it looks pretty damn trivial to me. If a programmer can't figure out those three lines they shouldn't be writing C++, let alone multithreaded C++.

Comment: @JonathanWakely +1 for the explanation, but the comment is a bit condescending, after all, this is a question/answer site... and writing multithreaded C++ is not something most programmers have experience with.

Comment: @rhalbersma, the relevant code above has almost nothing to do with multithreading. Create an object, set a value, return a wrapper for that value. It's trivial. I'm not expecting anyone to have experience with multithreading, but I do expect them to be able to understand the three lines above. If someone can't cope with that then they're not going to be able to cope with multithreading and having a `make_future` function isn't going to change that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Trivial to read vs trivial to write: understanding that code is a fair enough test of C++ skills; but having to come up with it is another matter. Perhaps that is what the authors of N3428 were trying to convey.

Comment: I've clearly stated my opinion that I disagree with them, it's trivial. You're not going to convince me otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Actually I think is still a matter of performance. Being able to return a future object with it's state containing requested value should be more efficient because promise.set_value() uses synchronization in order to set the "shared state".

Answer (score 0):

The thing with futures and promises is they are designed for multi-threaded usage. So if you want to return a future object you need to create it either via a `std::async` call, a `std::packaged_task<>` or a `std::promise<>`. If that's the case @ronag's answer is a hit.

If this is not a general case and you just want to return an indirection to your value you may use a `std::function` for direct computation, or a [caching mechanism](http://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/simple-little-cashing-variable-or-property-trick/) around it, or an [`Expected<T>`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C) value for handling errors too like the futures does; so you won't pay for the thread communication costs.